# Google maps v2 control position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm using Google maps api v2 with default UI, because the controls look much better when set to default

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
    function load() {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'),
        {mapTypes:[G_PHYSICAL_MAP]});
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(32.0000, 19.3000), 2);
        map.setUIToDefault();
    }
</script>
```

I want to place all controls (zoom and map type) on the right side. I know how to do it in V3 but here I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [positioning API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls#Control_Positioning)

```
var topRight = new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_TOP_RIGHT);
map.addControl(mapTypeControl, topRight);
```

Comment: this works only with normal controls, but it dosent when they are set to default